# Using larger array in a Fortran subroutine

Tags: arrays, fortran, subroutine

My Fortran code is below(test.f):

```
subroutine sub(n1,n2,wa)
implicit none
integer, intent(in)  :: n1, n2
real(4), intent(inout) :: wa(1_8:1_8*n1*n2)
integer(8) :: i, j, ms

print*, 'in sub, 1_8*n1*n2=', 1_8*n1*n2
print*, 'in sub, size of wa:', size(wa,kind=8)

ms=0
!$omp parallel default(shared) private(i,j,ms)
!$omp do 
    do i=1, n1
    do j=1, n2
       ms=(i-1)*n2+j
       wa(ms)=ms*1.d0
    enddo; enddo;
!$omp end do nowait
!$omp end parallel

print*, 'size of wa:', size(wa,kind=8)

return
end subroutine sub

program main
implicit none
integer, parameter :: n1=2**11,n2=2**20
real(4), allocatable :: wave(:)
integer :: ierr
integer(8) :: i

allocate(wave(1_8*n1*n2), stat=ierr)

!$omp parallel default(shared) private(i)
!$omp do
     do i=1_8,1_8*n1*n2
       wave(i)=0.d0
     enddo
!$omp end do nowait
!$omp end parallel


print*, 'in main, size of wave:', size(wave,kind=8)

call sub(n1, n2, wave)

print*, wave(1_8*n1*n2)

deallocate(wave, stat=ierr)
end program main
```

n1 and n2 can be larger, and make sure that n1*n2 is an long integer (>2**31-1).  I just want to test how to use very large array in a subroutine.

I compile with: `ifort -openmp -CB test.f`.

the array `wa` in subroutine `sub` will make an error if I use `-CB` option for checking bound of an array.

This is the error information:

> in main, size of wave:            2147483648
>   in sub, 1_8*n1*n2=            2147483648
>   in sub, size of wa:                     0
>   forrtl: severe (408): fort: (2): Subscript #1 of the array WA has
>   value 108003329 which is greater than the upper bound of -2147483648.

the number in the error information is random.

When I declare `wa` in subroutine as `real(4), intent(inout) :: wa(1)`, the program will run well. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Are you aware that a compiler may interpret `real(4), intent(inout) :: wa(1)` not as meaning that `wa` is an array of size 1 (but as assumed size)?  That may be significant depending on the "mistake" the compiler sees.  If you have a message from compiler (compiling or running) then please show it.

Comment: this is the error information:   forrtl: severe (408): fort: (2): Subscript #1 of the array WA has value 108003329 which is greater than the upper bound of -2147483648.  the number in the error information is random.

Comment: Please [edit] the question, do not use comments. No that using kinds numbers as `4` and `8` directly is not recommended and not portable. Those numbers are not numbers of bytes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter

Comment: I do not get any error message when I run your code. Also, the number `-2147483648` is suspicious. Please double-check that the code you show is exact and exactly corresponds to the error message.

Comment: when i set n1 and n2 smaller (n1*n2<2**31),  the program will be ok using -CB option.

Comment: OK, there is clearly some integer overflow involved. It does NOT happen with my Intel Fortran. Please report your exact compiler version and configuration like 32bit/64bit.

Comment: I don't get any error with ifort either (besides that the value shown by print*, wave(1_8*n1*n2) at the end is not zero)

Comment: if i compile with `gfortran -fopenmp --fbounds-check test.f`, there will be no problem. maybe this difference comes from the intel fortran.

Comment: I define a new `integer(8)` number `n` and `n=1_8*n1*n2`, then declare the array as `wa(n)`. The program will run well. So i think the problem come from that how the compiler deals with those declared parameters

Answer (score 0):

> forrtl: severe (408): fort: (2): Subscript #1 of the array WA has
>   value 108003329 which is greater than the upper bound of -2147483648

The index on the error may be random, but the upper bound is not. 
`-2147483648` is the result of the unchecked expression `2**11 * 2**20`, for the default integer (kind=int32), since the maximum representable number is `2**31-1 = 2147483647`.

You are declaring the upper bound of the dummy array inside the subroutine like this:

```
wa(1_8:1_8*n1*n2)
```

As both operation have the same precedence, maybe the compiler is multiplying n1 and n2 first, getting the negative result, and then multiplying by 1_8 to convert it to a larger kind. I can't test right now.

You could try using parentheses on the expression, and if you have access to a debugger, you can check the type and bounds of the variable at runtime.

Also, don't rely on "magic kind numbers" like 4 or 8. Thosr numbers are compiler dependent. You should use `selected_int_kind` or the constants on the intrinsic module `iso_fortran_env`.

Comment: I don't think the rules for Fortran expressions allow your explanation. If there is 1_8 at the beginning, the result must have at least kind 8. Also, I note, it does not happen with my Intel Fortran release.

Comment: Also note: `in sub, 1_8*n1*n2= 2147483648`

Comment: Actually, I do have the same problem, but the compiler does not complain. I do have `size(wa)=0`. But the explanation will be more subtle than what you propose. The expression has the correct kind. In gfortran `size(wa)=2147483648`.

Comment: Vladimir F is correct: the kind of the expression `a*b*c` (`a` of greater range than `b` and `c`) is that of `a`.  That isn't to say the compiler isn't doing `b*c` at the lower range but if it is that is a clear bug.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked the standard and NOTE 10.9 says it shall be left-to-right

Comment: i compile with intel fortran 2015 and run on centos 7.3.1611. i use `size(wa(1_8:1_8*n1*n2),kind=8)` which can get the right size of wa, so i think `1_8*n1*n2` is right.